# My photo slider, "owl carousel" places the photo's under each other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I'm working on a site, with 2 photo sliders from "[owl-carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/)".

The first slider works perfectly, but the second slider places all the photo's under each other.

Is it a problem in the jquery or just in the html?

```
<div class="modal-body">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12"> 

         <!-- portfolio media -->
         <div class="portfolio-images"> 

            <!-- image slider -->
            <div id="owl-portfolio1" class="owl -carousel">
               <div class="item active"> <img src="images/print1.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" title="" alt="" /> </div>
               <div class="item"> <img src="images/print2.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" title="" alt="" /> </div>
               <div class="item"> <img src="images/print3.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" title="" alt="" /> </div>
               <div class="item"> <img src="images/print4.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" title="" alt="" /> </div>
               <div class="item"> <img src="images/print2.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" title="" alt="" /> </div>
               <div class="item"> <img src="images/print3.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" title="" alt="" /> </div>
               <div class="item"> <img src="images/print4.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" title="" alt="" /> </div>
               <div class="item"> <img src="images/print2.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" title="" alt="" /> </div>
               <div class="item"> <img src="images/print3.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" title="" alt="" /> </div>
               <div class="item"> <img src="images/print4.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" title="" alt="" /> </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#owl-portfolio").owlcarousel({
        });
        $("#owl-portfolio").owlcarousel({
        });
    });
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: mind showing the relevant code which is causing the problem?

Comment: i would like to, but i can't put any thing down below, because of the low reputation. i did followed the tips of threeandme, it changed something, there is now only 1 picture but there is still no slider or buttons.

Comment: The lack of buttons could be due to the css. Make sure that you include the relevant classes in the div tags.

Comment: @Simonsays : add code in question...not comments, you just add it, i'll do necessary formatting if needed!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure each has a specific id selector like #owl-carousel-1 and #owl-carousel-2 then activate each one individually with the initiation code, changing the selector to suit each case.

```
<div id="owl-carousel-1" class="owl-carousel" >
  <!-- the carousel -->
</div>
<div id="owl-carousel-2" class="owl-carousel" >
  <!-- the second carousel -->
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#owl-carousel-1").owlCarousel();
  $("#owl-carousel-2").owlCarousel();

});
</script>
```

Comment: u mean, i've got to change de ccs? or i need to put this code in the source?

Comment: No, I mean that each carousel should have a different id tag. Then you can set up two calls as shown in the script tag

Comment: yeah, i've got that, i also put your script tag in, it changed a little bit, but it's still nog showing the buttons, or any signs of the slider.